# How do I store an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object `image` I can do things like `image.top` and it will return a value, or I can do `image.myPoints[0].left` and it will return a value.  I basically have this image object that stores values for me.  I want to be able to put multiple `image` objects in an array so i could do something like this:

```
$("#toPinpoint").mapImage({
                useAjax: false,
                pinpoints: [ { "top": 50,
                           "left": 280,
                           "width": 200,
                           "height": 200},
                         { "top": 0,
                           "left": 0,
                           "width": 300,
                           "height": 74 } ] 
            });
```

I use this function to create the object, the pinpoints get added on to the object.  When the mapImage function is called this is what happens:

```
    $.fn.mapImage = function(options){



    //Set user input options and defaults
    var optionConfig = $.extend({}, $.fn.mapImage.defaults, options);

    image=this;
    this.image = this;

    // Assign defaults
    this.previewMode = optionConfig.previewMode;
    this.pinpoints = optionConfig.pinpoints;
    image.pinpoints = optionConfig.pinpoints;
    image.pinpointCount = 0;
    image.selected = 0;
    ...}
```

This sets the image properties and now I want to modify the properities with my application then SAVE these `image` objects into an array.

My problem with this is that the array is loading up with image objects, but it seems to fill the whole array with the object i just pushed in, so it doesnt save my old image objects. For example, if i do `myArray[0].myPoints[0].left` , lets say it retruns 30, and then i push another image object that has myPoints[0].left equal to 20, the first image object I have in the array turns into 20 instead of saving it as 30.  If theres a good way of solving this issue it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. Can you post a more detailed code example? When you say "pop" another image, do you mean push? Because they have the opposite result.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: I meant push sorry, and yes I will put a more detailed example up

Comment: Your anti-patterns are showing: `image = this; this.image = this;` Hi, I'm a circular reference!

Answer (score 4):

Using `array.push(x)` should add `x` to the end of `array`. However, it will not create a copy of `x`, so if you then change an attribute of `x` and `push()` it again, your array will contain two instances of `x` with the updated attribute - I suspect this is what you are seeing. (That is, you may be changing the `top` property of your `image` and `push()`ing it again, instead of creating a whole new `image` to `push()`).

Comment: I think your absolutely right, but how would I go about fixing this? how do i create a new instance of this object every time I add it

Comment: Depends on how you're currently creating the object. It should be something like `var secondImage = new MyImage();`. I say "MyImage" rather than "Image" since the latter is already an existing DOM object in javascript. (Once again it'd be helpful to put up a more extensive code sample to get a better idea of what you've currently got :))

Comment: You need to "new" the image, not the array. How do you create the first image?

Comment: i have updated it with a better example, this is pretty much my code now

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

You need to use the "new" keyword.

Comment: I thought this at first too, but omitting the `new` keyword seems to work properly and passes lint.

Comment: Just because it passes lint doesn't mean it's the intended usage, and its unwise to use constructor functions without the `new` keyword.

Comment: I know, I wouldn't recommend using it without the `new`, and was surprised to see that it worked _and_ passed lint, because it just seems so horribly wrong to me.

Comment: @ken, what is the difference between var myArray = new Array(); and var myArray = [];

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this more complicated than need be.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.mapImage = function(options) {
    var defaults = { /* your defaults here */ };

    // Merge default options with passed in options and store
    options = ($.extend({}, defaults, options));

    // Do other stuff
  };
})(jQuery);

// Backup current pinpoints and modify the current one
$('#toPinpoints').data('pinpoints-backup', $('#toPinpoints').data('pinpoints').splice());
$('#toPinpoints').data('pinpoints')[0].top = 100;

// Push a new array of pinpoints
$('#toPinpoints').data('pinpoints').push({"top": 100, "left": 50, "width": 200, "height": 150});
```

Be careful with [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) as it does not operate recursively, so any arrays that are within the defaults sub-array will be completely overwritten by those in the options array, *not* merged.

If you'll need to access the pinpoints data later, you may wish to use [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) by doing something like `this.data($.extend({}, $.fn.mapImage.defaults, options));` instead of reassigning the options variable. The pinpoints for a given element could then be accessed anywhere by `$('#toPinpoint').data('pinpoints')` which will return the same array you passed in via options to `mapImage()`. You could then traverse all the pinpoints with [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

If I'm missing something in what you're trying to do, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, that definitely makes sense, but now how can I add multiple pinpoints to an array?  This gives me a set of pinpoints, now lets say I want to modify all these pinpoints' values and then push it into an array, so I have the OLD values and the NEW values

Comment: You can store anything in `jQuery.data()`, look at the [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for it. Calling `.data('pinpoints')[0].top = 100` should modify the current value. You can add new pinpoints via `.data('pinpoints').push(newPinpoints)`. If you need to make a backup of current data, you could do `.data('pinpoints-backup', .data('pinpoints).splice())`. (Note that I'm omitting the `this` keyword before `.data()` as you could be doing it outside and need to use a selector)

Comment: (I've edited my answer per my comment) (Sorry for the multiple comments in a row)