# How do I store different states of an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object called `apples` and if i do something like `apples[0].weight` it returns a value.  Now I want to be able to store an array of `apples`.  Lets call the array `myApples`.  How do I add multiple instances of `apples` to the `myApples` array without the values changing to the most updated one.  For example:

```
apples[0].weight = 10;
apples[1].weight = 20;
myApples.push(apples);
apples[0].weight = 15;
apples[1].weight = 16;
myApples.push(apples);
```

Now if I were to print the value `myApples[0].apples[0].weight` i get 15 instead of getting 10.  I think its because the reference is the same array, so it gets updated every time I change it.  How would I go about storing these `apple` "states" so I can keep a history of changes made to it.  Keep in mind I want to make this arbitrary, so I wouldnt have to make something like apples1, apples2, apples3, because the changes on this could be unlimited.(In my actual project I am storing pinpoints on a canvas, so i can basically do an "undo" and "redo" feature and want to store the values of these pinpoints every time something changes on the canvas.)

EDIT-
This is how I make `apples` or `pinpoints`:

```
var options = {pinpoints: [ { "top": 50,
                           "left": 280,
                           "width": 200,
                           "height": 200},
                         { "top": 0,
                           "left": 0,
                           "width": 300,
                           "height": 74 } ]}    
var optionConfig = $.extend({}, $.fn.mapImage.defaults, options);
var myPinpoints = optionConfig.pinpoints;
```

So if i do myPinpoints[0].left it gives me 280, I want to be able to push myPinpoints into an array then change myPinpoints[0].left to something else, and then push it on to the array again and save BOTH values

Comment: your apples array is invalid in that context

Comment: @kjy112 I don't think it's invalid; the problem described is real however.

Comment: Could you show how you you create `apples`? You say you have an *object* `apples`, I say you have an *array of objects* `apples`. So you want to create an array of arrays of objects?

Comment: hey I updated with my pinpoint example, pretty much same thing as the apple example

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your previous question less than a day earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012899/how-do-i-store-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery.clone kind of API to clone the Object and move it to your Stack or Queue.
This way you can ensure object states are maintained separately.

Answer (score 1):

Well what is it that you need "apples" for anyway?

```
myApples.push([
  { weight: 10 },
  { weight: 20 }
]);
myApples.push([
  { weight: 15 },
  { weight: 16 }
]);
```

Now if there's more to an apple than just "weight", maybe you need an apple-maker function:

```
function makeApple(weight, variety, color) {
  return {
    weight: weight,
    variety: variety || "Braeburn",
    color: color || "red"
  };
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
myApples.push([
  makeApple(10, "Fuji"),
  makeApple(20, "Granny Smith", "green")
]);
```

or whatever.

*edit* — as Felix King points out, the nature of "apples" isn't super clear. In any case, whatever "apples" is, personally I would lean towards making a more function-oriented setup to create the objects, or arrays, or arrays of objects, or whatever they are.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the object apples is reference based.  So even though you push them onto your array, when you change the value to 15, you are still changing the first apples object.  Try using the keyword 'new'.

```
var apples1 = new int[99];
var apples2 = new int[99];

apples1[0].weight = 10;
apples1[1].weight = 20;
myApples.push(apples1);
apples2[0].weight = 15;
apples2[1].weight = 16;
myApples.push(apples2);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! I wanted to make it arbitrary so i wouldn't have to make variables like apples1 and apples2 because the changes could be endless

Comment: `new int[99]` does not look like valid JS.

Comment: To be fair, it could be valid if `int` is an array and `int[99]` contains a constructor function, but I don't think that is what you had in mind. And if you did I have to ask: Why?

Comment: I didn't realize this was Javascript - to instantiate a new array in Javascript you would say 'new Array()' - make sure to capitalize the 'A'.  If it is behaving the way I think it is, when you add an item to an array you are only storing a memory reference.  So you are essentially pushing the same memory reference onto the array - essentially apples is only one variable - they will probably all be the same.  To do what you want you can programmatically declare new elements without creating var names.  If they are all the same memory reference apples will always equal apples.

Comment: @Payson Welch Yes you are exactly right, but i guess im trying to figure out how i can save these states into an array

Comment: @Payson Welch: Even better: `a = []`. Don't use `new Array()` (and the question is tagged with `javascript` btw ;)).

Answer (score 0):

Anthony,

Why not use 2-dimensional arrays instead?. e.g.

```
var apples = new Array(100);
apples[0]  = new Array(2);
apples[0][0] = {weight: 0};
apples[0][1] = {weight: 1};
apples[1]  = new Array(2);
apples[1][0] = {weight: 10};
apples[1][1] = {weight: 11};
```

Regards
        Neil

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand a little more here is how I would do it.  First define a coordinates object that contains x,y inputs.  Next setup a method to stack these pinpoints / coordinates, I am assuming you are working on an x,y grid.  I am loosely writing this code and not testing so take it with a grain of salt.

```
    // declare an array in global scope
var CoordinateCollection = new Array();

// create an object model
function Coordinate(x,y) { 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// this function will push a new coordinate onto the array
function AddCoordinate(x,y) { 
    CoordinateCollection.push(new Coordinate(x,y));
}

// after calling AddCoordinate you could now
// say something like
// alert(CoordinateCollection[0].x);
// if you call it again you could say
// alert(CoordinateCollection[1].x);
// and it would have a different value if the
// two original values were different.
```

EDIT...

You could just omit the call to AddCoordinate and use the line inside of it.